# How to add more metadata to user context on Bugsnag?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bugsnag

Apparently the Bugsnag [setUser](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/#identifying-users) method only accepts three params: `id`, `name` and `e-mail`. How to attach my custom metadata to the user, like the Sentry [setUserContext](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/#adding-context) method?

[image: setUser(id, name, email)]

---

I believe it's somehow possible because I see this image on [Custom Filters](https://docs.bugsnag.com/product/custom-filters/) page and it has a custom `subscription_level` field:

[image: https://docs.bugsnag.com/assets/images/product/features/custom-filters/add-from-dashboard.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugsnag Employee here.  You can do this! Here are the docs for react native and javascript

https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/#attaching-custom-diagnostics

https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/browsers/#custom-diagnostics

Comment: Thanks. The second link solution did not work on react native, but the first one did: `report.addMetadata('user', 'hello', 'world')`.

Comment: Although it would be much better if this was implemented in the `serUser` method, not in the `notify` one. So I opened this issue: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/issues/84